# The expression « je ne m'en suis pas laissé compter / conter »

Tags: expressions

> Homme : Personne n'a essayé de t'arrêter ?
>
> Femme : Tu penses bien que si ! Mais je ne m'en suis pas laissé **compter** / **conter** !

I’m trying to pin down the meaning of this expression. Does it mean:

> "But I wouldn’t hear of it." = "But I refused to listen to it."

Or is it more like:

> "But I was having none of it." = "But I refused to let that happen."

---

Incidentally, is it fine to use both "compter" and "conter" with this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *conter*, not *compter* which would be meaningless here.

*Ne pas s'en laisser [conter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conter)* means to avoid being cheated/seduced/fooled/manipulated by someone who is telling untrue/invented stories (*conter*) in order to abuse you.